# FirebaseUI-Android with Google Signin

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebaseui

I have read your README.dm from the firebaseui-android library. Can be found https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android. This will be the first time that I have used your Authentication for getting a user to login. I am currently only using the Google sign-in, but will add Facebook and Twitter in the future. In this README.dm keys section github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#add-facebooktwittergoogle-keys this is the only instructions for the Google sign-in.

> If you're using Google authentication, place your google-services.json in the app folder.

There is no mention of having to setup anything else for the Google sign-in to work. But at least in my app for the Google sign-in to work I needed to also setup the authentication for a web app which can be found www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html#section-configure. But if I configure the Web app authenitcation then I don't need to google-services.json. Why is your library not using the google-services.json but instead only using the web app. This is not a web app as it is a native Android app. I think that this also leads to the user being logged out if they do not use the app after the expiration unix time returned in you authData.

All I want to do is log a user into my app using either Google, in the future Facebook or Twitter, and not have to have them re-login if they don't use my app for a few days. If you library cannot log a user in using the native and keep them logged in then I guess I will have to write the login myself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know for sure what you want but I think the Firebase team was trying to make the document more concise for everyone. You have to do some of the work yourself.

So I will just drop this links and run

1. Create a project in Google Developers Console https://console.cloud.google.com/project
2. Click on "Get a Configuration File" https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start
3. Know that I did not (actually, could not) give you all the information you may need because I am also working on something. Just like you.